# Duplex communication between client and service in azure

Tags: c#, azure, communication, duplex, webrole

i've been trying for a couple days making a duplex communication with a service present on WebRole in Azure. I add a reference of service to my client (console aplication running locally) and when try to call methods on service it never works.
If i try on azure emulator everything works fine.

Does anyone knows how to do that correctly? Where can i find tutorials with step by step works to do that ? I already made a lot of researches but any works or explains this.

Comment: You have to narrow it down a little. Does your call reach the service? Does it leave your computer? Does it leave the application?

Comment: Is this a WCF Service using wsDualHttpBinding?  Also, a fiddler trace will help isolate it to a client or service side issue.

Comment: I think your network firewall or proxy is blocking the outgoing connection. And for Duplex communication check Windows Azure Service Bus.